# How to call different functions for same route based on sanctum auth middleware failure?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-routing, laravel-sanctum

I have a route

```
/** PROTECTED ROUTES */
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:sanctum']], function () {
    Route::post('/cart/add-product', [CartController::class, 'addProductToCart']);
});
```

This route should add products to UserCart if user is authenticated i.e we can get a user_id with the help of `$request->user()` .
In case user is not authenticated a unique user_id will be provided by front-end.
Based on this, I want the route to remain same but function called should be different so that, if user is authenticated the product will be added to their UserCart else it will be added to their TemporaryCart

Comment: It sounds like you should remove the middleware from the route (since you want the route to work regardless) and let the controller check if the user is authenticate or not. Then the controller can determine how the request should be handles (where and how it should be saved, for example).

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thanks for replying. How can I check in controller if a request is authenticated or not. `$request->user()` doesn't return a user if i remove the middleware. So how can I get the user from a request?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove middleware and check it in the controller. It is right what is controller supposed to do :)

Just a little improvement, you can do this like:

```
Route::post('/cart/add-product', 'CartController@addProductToCart');
```

In your controller you can have something like this. (Don't copy that it is just for an inspiration)

```
public function addProductToCart(Request $request, $id) {
   if (!empty($id)) {
      return $this->handleNewUser();
   else
      return $this->handleAuthUser();
}

private function handleNewUser() {
   //add to temporary cart
}

private function handleAuthUser() {
   //add to users cart
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I don't know how I can get an authenticated user instance from a request?

Comment: In the top of your controller use:
`use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth`
Then in your function `Auth::user()` will return instance of auth user :)

Comment: It doesn't work. `Auth::user()` returns null, even if i supply bearer token